# Counter for variables combined into separate commands

Tags: bash

I need to figure code for following scenarios:

I need to set packageN and productN variables, this should be done via loop and counter I suppose. Then based on how many packages and product I get it will run corresponding amount of commands. This is scenario with 2 packages and 2 products:

```
    package1=packageA
    package2=packageB

    product1=productA
    product2=productB

    somecommand --package $package1 --product $product1
    somecommand --package $package1 --product $product2
    somecommand --package $package2 --product $product1
    somecommand --package $package2 --product $product2
```

This could get very complicated as I need for example 10 packages for 10 products and above code would not be very optimal, I believe there should be easy way  how to do this eg:

```
    n=o
    while true; do
    echo specify package name:
    read package$n

    echo Do you have another package?
    read yesno

    if [[ $yesno = n ]]; then
    break
    else
    ((n++))
    done
```

the same loop for product, but then I don't know how to build above commands based on how many variables I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
packages=( package-1 package-2 package-3 )
products=( product-1 product-2 product-3 )

for package in "${packages[@]}"
do
    for product in "${products[@]}"
    do
        somecommand --package "$package" --product "$product"
    done
done
```

Comment: I love this site, everything gets so easy! Thanks a lot, the script is perfect and simple. Only thing I changed is to "read" packages array, but I quickly learnt "read -a" does the job, thanks again!